# Using a past tense "mingled" in present tense writing

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

The sentence is:

> "As I mingled with the crowd, I keep an eye out for my friend."

Is that grammatically correct?
I'm writing something in present tense instead of past tense for the first time, so I'm super confused.
Or is it "As I mingle with the crowd.."?

Comment: This is incorrect. Past tense mingled must agree with the verb in the main sentence which would be "kept". Alternately, you could as "While mingling with the crowd, I keep an eye out for my friend."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This is for serious linguists and etymologists, instead, try our sister site [ell.se] for help learning English.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when your action takes place. Are you speaking about something that happened today, yesterday in the past? Because of the use of ***as***, you must use the two verbs in the same tense, as it implies simultaneity.

Consider the following options

1. if the actions occurred in the past

> As I mingled with the crowd, I kept an eye out for my friend.

or

> As I was mingling with the crowd, I was keeping an eye out for my friend.

2. if the actions are taking place in the present

> As I am mingling with the crowd, I am keeping an eye out for my friend.

I am not saying that I have exhausted all the possibilities, but given the vagueness of the situation in time in your context, this is what I came up with.